# What's the difference, "It feels like spring." and "I feel like spring."?

Tags: sentence-meaning

When I was watching a video on You tube, a man said, looking at flowers, "It feels like spring." and soon after that he also said, "I feel like spring."
Is there any difference in meaning? Or are they interchangeable?  Then how about these sentences?  Today is Friday, and I might say, It doesn't feel like Friday. Can I also say, "I don't feel like Friday."? Could you explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It* is how English refers to the weather, or to seasons, or to time... it's spring, it's raining, it's five o'clock, it's Friday. These are idiomatic and said all the time, or at least when appropriate or "in season"...

Most people don't go around saying *I* feel like spring  or *I* feel like Friday or 5 o'clock, etc. This is a simile (a comparison using' like' or 'as')  rather than an expression you are going to hear often. It's not something I've ever said, although I love spring!

In any case, "I feel like Spring" definitely does **not** mean the same thing as "It feels like Spring". The latter means that the world has Spring-like qualities, while the former can be interpreted as something like "I feel like doing things today that are typical things to do in Spring."

Comment: It is helpful to know which sentences sound natural and which sentences don't.  Thank you.

Comment: @tennisgirl you are welcome. glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

"It feels like spring": The man senses (sees, hears, smells, and feels) spring-like qualities in the world around him.

"I feel like spring": The man notices that his internal mental state matches feelings he has had during past spring days.

"It doesn't feel like Friday": Something you noticed about this Friday doesn't match your idea of what Friday should feel like.

"I don't feel like Friday": Something occurred on this Friday that makes you wish today were not Friday.

Comment: I agree with the first three; I'm not so sure about that last one. (That said, the last sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me, so I'm not sure **what** it should mean!)